# Creating a "download server"

Tags: debian

I'm not sure if "download server" is the proper term but I want to create a server on a Debian Linux base that can download files referenced to from my phone or computer. As an example, I'm browsing the web on my phone away from home and I find a ISO that I'd like to download to try in VirtualBox later. So I 'tell' my download server at home to download the file and when I get home, it has been downloaded and is ready to use. How would I go about this and how would I interface with the server?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realise this wasn't the right place for this question. I'll use Super User next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple website where you can submit a URL to which gets saved in a text file on the Debian server.  Have a cron job run on the Debian server which checks for the existence of that file and then if it finds it, it runs wget on the URL in the file and deletes the text file.

Comment: Superb answer! Thanks very much. I'll mark the answer as accepted as soon as it lets me...